# How to add a post without assigning to a category?

Tags: categories, permalinks

Can any one please explain how to add a post in WordPress without assigning it to any category.

Actually I want to display some news or some quick information.  So, it does not come to any category in my blog.  In this type of time, I do not want to assign to any category.

for example,

http://www.someSiteURL.com/this-is-news-about-something-awesome/

http://www.someSiteURL.com/wordpress-themes/Anan-wordpress-theme-review/

The first url is what i want to have.  But by default, it automatically add "uncategorized".

My permalink structure is "/%category%/%postname%/"  and I use Yoast to hide the word "category" in the urls.

Any one can help on this situation please?

And kindly i would like to let you know that, I do not want to add page for such things.  Also, I do not want to add categories like "news" or "info" for this.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: You can't do that. The post will be assigned to "Uncategorized" category by default. However you can remove `/%category%/` from permalink structure to hide category name from URL (and you'll not need the plugin anymore). Read about [using permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) first.

Comment: If you look at the yoast.com site, you can see urls like http://yoast.com/500-website-reviews/ and at the same time, you can see urls like http://yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo/  .  They both are posts.  I checked it by viewing the source.  (the body tag contains single-post class).  How yoast has achieved that feature in his WP site?

Comment: Yoast's `Articles` are pages.

Comment: No, They are posts.  If you look inside the "view source"  you can check the body tag.  The tag for the post http://yoast.com/500-website-reviews/ contains class="single single-post postid-68173.  SO, it must be a post.  Generally in page the body tag will contain class="page page-id-2" similar things.

Comment: What about [yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo](http://yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo/) what you've mentioned in 'They both are posts'?

Comment: yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo/ is a post.  It contains "category" named "articles" slug.  In the post yoast.com/500-website-reviews/  url it does not contains any category slug.  Both are posts.  I hope you get my point.

Comment: Also, please note that I have made well research and posted this question.  Moreover, I am a blogger and running a site http://blog.pixelthemes.com/ where my PR is 4 and main domain PR is 5 with 50K alexa rank.  Additionally I am a theme designer.  I am not a newbie in WP.  I am just trying to enhance my skills in WP.  I am not sure why i have been voted down for this question.

Comment: I found the solution.  Yes it is possible.  I shall post it as answer after 5 hours from now.  Because, I am not able to post answer now as i am new here.

Comment: [yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo](http://yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo/) source: `<div class="post-607 page type-page status-publish hentry entry">`. Best wishes in enhancing your skills.

Comment: In the article, Yoast specifically explains that he use pages to display posts, so he could control SEO... (Point 4.1)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the solution to the question I asked above.  It is possible to get such permalinks by using plugins like

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/  (I tried it and worked)
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-editor/

The first plugin "custom-permalinks" allows admin to edit the slug including category.  So, it is now possible to make the permalink in anyway you want.

This is what i setup in the WordPress.

First I set the permalinks to /%category%/%postname%/  So the site by default will display permalink with category name.

Suppose, If i do not want to display the category name, I can use the permalink editor to get the permalink url the way i want.

I am just posting the answer, so people can make use of it.

Comment: Thanks!! The first plug in works to perfection to fix this issue.